# how to print formated text from keyboard

Tags: ios, swift

I was wondering how can I print formated text from the keyboard keys. For example, I have a toolbar attached to the keyboard, I click `"bold"` on the keyboard and from there on every letter printed from the keyboard will now be bold. This is what I have but it does not work, String's don't seem to hold format.

```
  func keyPressed(sender: AnyObject?) {
       let button = sender as! UIButton
       let title = button.titleForState(.Normal)

       let attrs = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(15)]
       let boldString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:title!, attributes:attrs)


       (textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput).insertText(boldString.string)
  }
```

Comment: You can use `NSAttributedString` for the same, perform calculation on key press.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. NSAttributedString won't work with insertText.

Comment: This can be achieved by `NSAttributedString`. you can verify it in answer given by @TwoStraws

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings don't hold format, you're right. You should manipulate your target directly, using `NSAttributedString` and `attributedText` to do so.

```
let str = "Hello, world!"
let attrs = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)]

let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: str, attributes: attrs)
yourTextView.attributedText = attributedString
```

Note that the specific thing you want to do is tricky, because attributed strings attach attributes (like bold) to parts of text and not "from there on every letter". So if you read out the current attributed string then try to modify the attributes at the caret without actually inserting anything, it won't work.

So, this won't work:

```
let existingAttributedString = yourTextView.attributedText.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableAttributedString
let newAttrs = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(15)]
let newAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "", attributes: newAttrs)
existingAttributedString.appendAttributedString(newAttributedString)
```

Whereas this will:

```
let existingAttributedString = yourTextView.attributedText.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableAttributedString
let newAttrs = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(15)]
let newAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: " ", attributes: newAttrs)
existingAttributedString.appendAttributedString(newAttributedString)
```

The only difference is that the second example inserts a space, which is enough for iOS to attach attributes to.

That being said, if you're willing to change your approach so that users *select existing text* before hitting bold, that works great.

Comment: Thank you for the input this is very helpful but, it is a requirement that they are able to type in a text editor fashion. but I do have one other question, in order to type "from there on" and apply a format like bold, do I have to know the instance of the uitextview or can it be applied to any uitextview?

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct; I realise it's not what you want, but that's how iOS works :)  You could, if you wanted, store the new attributes in a property then wait for a delegate callback when the user types a character. You could then catch the character, reject it, then insert it as an attributed string with the attributes you stored earlier. Regarding your extra question: you can use any text view, because you'll get given a reference to it in the delegate callback.

Comment: Thank you very much that makes it much more clear. I am new to ios development and I am not sure how everything works on it yet. Your posts are very helpful.

Comment: No problem – glad to help!